# Updating dc.js Legend Labels On Composite Chart Causes Group To Disappear

Tags: javascript, charts, legend, linechart, dc.js

I'm attempting to make a live (updated every 2 seconds) composite line chart in dc.js. I have the actual chart working as intended, but I'm having problems with the legend. The way I have it set up is I create the chart with some initial data like so:

```
        var cf = crossfilter(data);
        var minutes = cf.dimension(function(d){return d.negMinutes});
        var goodGroup = minutes.group().reduceSum(function(d){
            return d.numStreamsGood;
        });
        var fairGroup = minutes.group().reduceSum(function(d){
            return d.numStreamsFair;
        });
        var poorGroup = minutes.group().reduceSum(function(d){
            return d.numStreamsPoor;
        });

        streamChart = dc.compositeChart("#stream-chart");

        streamChart.dimension(minutes).x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-60, 0]))
            .width((window.innerWidth - 130) * 0.95)
            .height((window.innerHeight - 158) * 0.6)
            .transitionDuration(0)
            .xAxisLabel("Minutes Ago")
            .yAxisLabel("Number of Streams")
            .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
            .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
            .elasticY(true)
            .legend(dc.legend().x(60).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
            .renderlet(function(chart){
                chart.selectAll("g.x text")
                    .text(function(d){
                        return -1 * d;
                    });
            });

        streamChart.compose([
            dc.lineChart(streamChart)
                .group(goodGroup, "Good")
                .colors(['#248221']),
            dc.lineChart(streamChart)
                .group(fairGroup, "Fair")
                .colors(['#FF7A00']),
            dc.lineChart(streamChart)
                .group(poorGroup, "Poor")
                .colors(['#DE2B1E'])
        ]);

        streamChart.render();
```

Then, every two seconds, I update the data array, re-create the groups with the updated data, and re-draw the chart like this:

```
        streamChart.children()[0].group(goodGroup);
        streamChart.children()[1].group(fairGroup);
        streamChart.children()[2].group(poorGroup);

        streamChart.redraw();
```

The problem comes from the fact that I'm not providing a name when calling .group on the update, and so the legend simply has 0's for the names. When I try to add a name argument to the group function, the legend updates correctly, but causes some weird problems.

First, the groups that I assign names disappear from the chart (for example, if I use (goodGroup, "Good"), the line chart based off the goodGroup group disappears from the compositeChart).

Second, the color associated with that group in the legend changes to black (for example, the chart using goodGroup has green lines. After updating the group, it shows up as black in the legend).

Finally, hovering over the affected group(s) instead highlights the remaining groups (for example, only updating goodGroup and then hovering over its legend label highlights the fairGroup and poorGroup charts simultaneously).

Sorry if that sounds confusing. Here are some screenshots of what I'm talking about:

[Not trying to update the names/labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR2WW.png)

[What happens when I update with streamChart.children()[0].group(goodGroup, "Good");](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA3Zs.png)

Comment: It wasn't allowing me to post more than two links, so here's another screenshot:

[What happens when I update like above and hover over the "Good" label in the legend](http://i.imgur.com/jb4yzrb.png)

Comment: Not to say that this shouldn't work, bou are really stretching the bounds of dc.js here. Did you try just updating the existing crossfilter by using remove and add, rather than replacing it?

Comment: Yep, it has much the same problem. However, I did some more poking around and found that it's not the updating that's causing the problem, but instead seems to be the assignment of colors. When I disable the update function, I still get black for colors and no lines being drawn. However, when I change the .colors for each of the individual line charts to .ordinalColors, everything works fine, even with the updating and legend names.

Comment: Sounds like you understand the bug pretty well by now. Indeed legends are pretty new and I'm not terribly surprised. Would you please [file an issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/new) and link to whatever materials you've found, including this page? There are a lot of moving parts, and interacting parts, to keep track of in dc! Thank you for the in depth diagnosis.